# PHP SoapFault not caught by exception handlers

Tags: php, soap, exception

I am new to PHP exception handling and SOAP. For some reason I cannot catch a SoapFault. I don't know why. The soap server is not mine.

```
try { 
    $contact_id = $objSoapClient->getContactIdFromVisitorId('12345');
} 
catch (SoapFault $sf) { 
    echo "Soapfault"; 
} 
catch (Exception $e) { 
    echo "Exception"; 
}
```

I am purposely passing in the bad id 12345. When I enable errors I see the following message `SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Invalid Visitor ID`. However, my catch SoapFault block nor my catch Exception block ever get hit. Why?

Comment: does your function getContactIdFromVisitorId throwing exception ?

Comment: I assume so since when I enable errors I see the SoapFault exception error message I included at the end of my question `[SOAP-ENV:Client] Invalid Visitor ID`

Comment: I will add that the web service appears to be returning an actual SoapFault object to the variable `$contact_id`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem turned out to be my SoapClient declaration. There is an exceptions parameter that must be set in order for the exceptions to trigger.

```
$objSoapClient = new SoapClient('https://mywebservice.com/foo.wsdl', array(
    "trace" => false,  
    "exceptions" => true,     // <-------------- This!!!                                               
    'login' => 'username',    //username
    'password' => 'password', //password
    'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS + SOAP_USE_XSI_ARRAY_TYPE 
));
```

Comment: thank you for this. this was also getting me. why the default behavior would be to hide exceptions, I cannot imagine.

Answer (score 36):

The code you've submitted appears to be correct. Here's the only thing that comes to my mind.

With that said, if the code is located inside a class that define a namespace, you code will not work as it will try to reference Exception as \namespace\Exception which does not exist. "Passive" references such as those in `catch` clauses or `instanceof` expressions are permitted because the missing class could be loaded later.

For it to work, you have to prefix the class name with a slash (i.e. \Exception) to tell PHP to use PHP from the global space (or root if you want to call it that) (PHP) as opposed to your namespace;

```
<?php

namespace test;

class Foo
{
  public function bar()
  {
    try
    {
      something_that_might_break();
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
      // this will work
    }
  }
}

?>
```

You can find lots of information about namespaces here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php.

Comment: This was the reason my soap exceptions were going uncaught. Thank you.

Comment: Drat! Foiled again by namespaces! I have a new-found appreciation for Java and static typing!