# How to handle and work with fatal Errors

Tags: php

I'm running a php script against an appliance that's worked great up until recently when a special circumstance has caused a fatal error.

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("/var/www/blah/someWSDL.wsdl", array('trace'=>true, 'exceptions'=>true,'location'=>"https://hostName:8443/axl",'login' => "userName",'password'=> "password"));

$response = $soapClient->getLine(array("routePartitionName"=>"PT-INHOUSE", "pattern"=>"$row[callingPartyNumber]"));
echo "<TR><TD class='body'>" .  $response->return->line->description . "</TD><TD class='body'>"
```

So, this will work in any situation where $response yields an output.  However, there are situations where it will not (very rare).  In those cases, this is generated;

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server] Item not valid:
```

In reading up on the issue, it sounds like what I should be doing is "catching" the error.  In the event that the fatal error occurs, I would like to bypass echoing $response->return->line->description and replace this output with text like "nothing found".  Is this possible to do with an if statement, such as "if fatal error occurs, output this"?  From what I've read, this is not something that is recommended.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374345/php-soapfault-not-caught-by-exception-handlers

Comment: There's no answer that's universally valid. Ideally, you should determine why `SoapFaul` is being thrown: whether it's a logic error on your side or it's a run time issue you can't control.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, this is not a logic error.  I know why the error is occurring and it's, believe it or not, completely normal.  I'm generating a report from a database then using objects from the db to search in another db.  However, the object in the second DB may no longer be there as a normal course of business.

Comment: You should then catch the exception and ensure your code recovers gracefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally talking, you should avoid errors by checking the conditions in which errors get thrown, and avoid these. If you cannot avoid the errors, use this construction:

```
try {
    // code that produces errors
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e -> getMessage ();
    echo "Nothing found.";
}
```

Further information: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp

Comment: I'd advice against catching exceptions just to print them. There's no clear benefit and you merely loose the associated features—for instance, you can't have a site-wide error handler that logs or reports it properly.

Comment: This a good point, but generally talking, this is the solution. A side-wide implementation is the very best result. Also, checking the error type and handling it properly is necessary.

Comment: I understand what you're saying.  Some context.  The script first goes to a MySQL db and searches for a list of extension that made the most long distance calls.  However, the database does not contain the names of the users who made the calls.  The second part of the query takes extension from the first db and checks a second db for the user's names.  However, as I discovered, the extension may actually be deleted from the second db because the user left or the extension was decommissioned.  The data from the first db's output is still super important, but I just can't do the second query.

Comment: This sounds like a bad architecture, but I know that sometimes you just cannot get around it. For this, I'd advice to first check if the second database has any entries by querying with COUNT. If it has, run your normal query. I hope I got you right.

Comment: NikxDA - no, this would not work because it can create a situation where, if the object does not occur in the second db then don't output the content from the first db.  Even if an extension has been decommissioned, I still need to know if there was any long distance activity for it (in case an investigation needs to be made).  For sure, it's not ideal.

Comment: Then, use the code provided in my answer. Wrap the `echo`-line inside a try-block, and in the catch-block (which only gets called on errors), `echo "Nothing found.";`.