# __soapCall is returning nothing

Tags: php, soap

I've got the following function:

```
public function query($sql)
{
    $query = array(
    "queryString"=>$sql
    );
    $queryWrapper = array(
    "query"=>$query
    );

    try {
        $result = $this->_client->__soapCall("query", $queryWrapper, null, $this->_header);
    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
      $this->_client->__getLastResponse();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

The problem is that I can use `var_dump('anything');exit;` before the `__soapCall()`, and I see 'anything'. But if I `var_dump('stuff');exit;` AFTER the `__soapCall()`, I get just a blank page. I `var_dump('something');exit;` in the catch, but I don't see that. It's still just a blank page. My question is, what could be causing this? I would think that if the table in my query didn't exist, or something was wrong with my query at all, I'd get some sort of error. But I'm getting absolutely squat all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374345/php-soapfault-not-caught-by-exception-handlers Please check, I believe your problem is solved in answers

Comment: @DmytroZasiadko: I've tried both answers, and get the same results I've listed above.

Comment: So did you try to enable exceptions passing `"exceptions" => true` to soap client constructor and catching `\Exception $e` at the same time?

Comment: @DmytroZasiadko: that's correct.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you see a blank page, it's probably that the server is responding that. Try to find the status of the transaction. If you have 500 for instance, server is throwing an error,  if you have a 200, server is responding that, void.

Comment: did you try `catch (\SoapFault $e)`? because if your function in class with namespace php will try to find SoapFault class within this namespace

Comment: If you are seeing a blank page and post-call var_dump() is not being displayed, it's possibly due to a premature script termination inside your soap call. [Try temporarily activating error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) (add the code somewhere before your call) to see if you can see on-screen exception reporting.

Comment: In your catch do `var_dump($e)`. I assume it will contain something indicating what the issue is.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Tray adding this two lines in start of the function and try again i think in function there is warning or errors so its stoping php script

Answer (score 0):

I would try these scenarios:

**1. Correct Exceptions**

Is `$this->_client` instance of standard `\SoapClient`? If not, there could be different exceptions thrown that your `catch` ignores. If you are on `PHP 7.0` and above try catching `\Throwable` if on older versions try catching `\Exception`.

**2. Run in isolation**

If the problem persists it would be better to isolate this function from your codebase and try running it separately. You can even try online tools like [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/).

**3. Xdebug**

If you still cannot find the cause, it is best to trace the issue with [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/). You can find a simple setup tutorial for [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) and [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) here: https://medium.com/@pablofmorales/xdebug-with-docker-and-phpstorm-786da0d0fad2